# How to use a modal popup extender with update panel

Tags: asp.net

I have a webpage that has a dropdown list, Linkbutton and ModualPopupExtender. Inside the panel for the modualpopupextender is a textbox and an 'OK' button and a 'Cancel' button.

So what happens is that when the user clicks the linkbutton the popup panel comes up and the user enters a string in the textbox. Then the user clicks the 'OK' button and the popup goes away and the string entered in the popup textbox is now on the dropdown text.

The problem is that when the user clicks the 'OK' button the page does the postback and the screen goes black for a second then the webpage appears with the string in the dropdown text.

I would like to use an updatepannel so when the user clicks the 'OK' button the transition is seemless. But I can't get that to work.

Here is my Source Code:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="UpdatePannel.aspx.vb" Inherits="PDFforms.UpdatePannel" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .modalBackground
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            filter: alpha(opacity=60);
            -moz-opacity: 0.6;
            opacity: 0.6;
        }

        .popup
        {
            background-color: #ddd;
            margin: 0px auto;
            width: 330px;
            position: relative;
            border: Gray 2px inset;
        }


    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">


    <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">

    </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
   <div>     


            <table border="0" style="border-width: 2px; width: 100%; background-color:lightgray">

                <tr id="tr8">
                    <th colspan="6">PRODUCT INFORMATION</th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="tr3">

                    <td>PRODUCT FORM
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbProductForm" Font-Size="XX-Small" runat="server">ADD</asp:LinkButton>
                        <br />
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProductForm" Width="100px" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="0"> </asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="1">LIQUID</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2">SOLID</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="3">GAS</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList></td>                    
                </tr>
                </table>
        </div>        
        <div> 
            <%-- ------------------------------------------------------------Product popup------------------------------------------------------------------------------ --%>

                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" CssClass="popup"  runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                <fieldset>

                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Product Form Name:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtProductFormName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnProdFormName" runat="server" Text="Enter" Style="margin-left: 100px" OnClick="btnProdFormName_Click" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnCancel1" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                    </fieldset>
            </ContentTemplate>

           </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender2" runat="server" PopupControlID="UpdatePanel1" TargetControlID="lbProductForm" DropShadow="true" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" CancelControlID="btnCancel1" PopupDragHandleControlID="Panel1" OnOkScript="onOk()">
            </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my codebehind:

```
Public Class UpdatePannel
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnProdFormName_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnProdFormName.Click
        Dim ss As String
        ss = txtProductFormName.Text


        ddlProductForm.Items.Add("New")
        ddlProductForm.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem(ss))
        ddlProductForm.SelectedIndex = 0
    End Sub
End Class
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thank you

Comment: Hi, If this answer was helpful please vote and accept it. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Keep your `UpdatePanel` within `ModalPopupExtender` control and use a `AsyncPostBackTrigger` to call your OK button's click event asynchronously

E.g.

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender2" runat="server" PopupControlID="UpdatePanel1" TargetControlID="lbProductForm" DropShadow="true" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" CancelControlID="btnCancel1" PopupDragHandleControlID="Panel1" OnOkScript="onOk()">

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" CssClass="popup"  runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                <fieldset>

                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Product Form Name:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtProductFormName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnProdFormName" runat="server" Text="Enter" Style="margin-left: 100px" OnClick="btnProdFormName_Click" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnCancel1" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                    </fieldset>
            </ContentTemplate>

<Triggers> 
       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnProdFormName" EventName="Click" /> 
</Triggers> 
           </asp:UpdatePanel>

</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Comment: Hi, If this answer was helpful please vote and accept it. Cheers!